# Why does increasing simplex noise dimension wash it out?

Tags: image-processing, noise, procedural-generation

I just tried using [this approach](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise/23639#23639) to create a tiling 2d simplex noise function with [Gustavson's java implementation](http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/SimplexNoise.java). The result tiled, but the texture seemed muddy / washed out.

I decided to compare the result of using the 2d, 3d & 4d versions to make a 2d texture by holding any 'extra' dimension parameters at zero. The 4d output looked the same as my tiled 2d output. Furthermore, I noticed a trend: as the dimensions increase, the noise starts to drift away from the min & max toward the average. Here are the results along with their histograms:

[image] [image] [image]

I ran across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885440/why-does-simplex-noise-seem-to-have-more-artifacts-than-classic-perlin-noise) discussing some artifacts in Gustavson's implementation & wondered if that might be contributing to the problem, so I tried using [OpenSimplex noise](https://gist.github.com/KdotJPG/b1270127455a94ac5d19) instead & got very similar results.

What's going on here? I'd like to use the 4d simplex noise to make a tiling 2d texture that looks more like the 
regular 2d simplex noise. If necessary I can try to massage the output, but that seems like hack & I'd rather 
treat the problem rather than the symptoms if possible.

Again, just to clarify, I'm asking: why does the dimensionality seem to affect the final 2D as illustrated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313259/tiling-simplex-noise

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Simplex noise has no noticeable directional artifacts (is visually isotropic), though noise generated for different dimensions are visually distinct (e.g. 2D noise has a different look than slices of 3D noise, and it looks increasingly worse for higher dimensions[citation needed]).", so sounds like what you got

Comment: Also from wikipedia "For higher dimensions, n-spheres around n-simplex corners are not densely enough packed, reducing the support of the function and making it zero in large portions of space."

Comment: You might want to also insure that all dim are returning full range values..some implementation do not.

Comment: http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf says "Note in particular that a 3D section of 4D simplex noise is different from 3D simplex noise. This is the visual result of moving from the time-consuming interpolation one dimension at a time to a fast, direct summation." but they all seem to use summation so I don't understand

Comment: It might also be related to the different sets of possible gradients that are allowed in each dimension?  "For 2D, 8 or 16 gradients distributed around the unit circle 
is a good choice. For 3D, Ken Perlin’s recommended set of gradients is the midpoints of each 
of the 12 edges of a cube centered on the origin. … For 4D, a suitable set of gradients is the midpoints of each of the 32 edges of a 4D hypercube"

Comment: This may be related to the phenomenon discussed in this [paper on wavelet noise](https://graphics.pixar.com/library/WaveletNoise/paper.pdf), where taking a 2D slice through a higher-dimensionality gradient noise loses the band-limited characteristics of a native 2D version.